# Xpath looking for an attribute

Tags: xml, xpath

So I have the following XML:

```
<root>
    <people>

        <person id="a01">
            <name>Jack</name>
        </person>

        <person id="a02">
            <name>George</name>
        </person>


    </people>

    <groups>
        <group groupId="g01">
            <member refId="a01" />
            <member refId="a02" />
        </group>
    </groups>
</root>
```

And I was looking for the name of all the name of the persons in the group with the groupId g01. What I was trying to do was :

```
//name[@id=//group[@groupId='g01']/member/@refId]/text()
```

But apparently it doesn't work.

Cant I use an expression when looking for an attribute? How can I solve my problem then?

Im getting really confused because when there is an xpath problem its always involving idrefs and I just cant understand how to solve them if I cant store any variables in xpath.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure I correctly understood your problem, so let me know if below solution doesn't work as expected

```
//people/person[@id=//group[@groupId="g01"]/member/@refId]/name/text()
```

This should allow you to get `name` if the value of `@id` of parent `person` node is in list of `@refId` values from `member` nodes that are children of `group` with `@groupId="g01"`

Comment: Exacly what I wanted Thank you!

Comment: @ArmanFreitas, welcome! You can [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) if it solved your problem